# jQuery looping over objects of a PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a php array that looks like this when I print it out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Much title
            [end] => Such end
            [start] => Very start
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Much title
            [end] => Such end
            [start] => Very start
        )

)
```

I've sent this array to my jQuery like so:

```
var orders = <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>;
```

When I do `cosole.log(orders);` I get 2 objects obviously.

Output:

[image]

Now I want to loop over them I tried like so:

```
jQuery.each( orders, function( key, value ) {
      console.log( key + ": " + value );
});
```

This is giving me this output in my console:

```
0: [object Object]
1: [object Object]
```

Instead of the `title`, `start` and `end` values of every object.

Anyone has any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `console.log( key, value );`instead

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan How can I access the `title`, `start` and `end` values?

Comment: [each docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) it's `index, value`, not key; you need to drill down one further level to get at the content of `value`

Comment: `value.title` - `value.start` - `value.end`

Comment: @mjr index or key is merely the variable name. Both will work.

Comment: @Daan well yes, but it seems to have caused confusion here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate the object properties, you need a second loop, because `value` is the object itself.

```
jQuery.each( orders, function( key, value ) {
      jQuery.each(value, function(propertyName, propertyValue){
          console.log( propertyName + ": " + propertyValue);
      });
});
```

Or you can access the properties directly by name:

```
jQuery.each( orders, function( key, value ) {
    console.log( value.title );
});
```